# Maximum sum of BST-subtree in a non-BST binary tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

For the below binary tree the problem statement says the maximum sum of a BST-subtree in the binary tree is 20 (rooted at 3), but why not include the root node as well (with value of 1) to obtain an even larger sum of 21?

Thanks in advance.

```
     1
    / \
   /   \
  4      3
 / \    / \
2   4   2  5
          / \
         4   6
```

Comment: The root isn't a BST.

Comment: Don't know which problem you are referring to, but it probably says: find the maximum sum of all nodes of any subtree

Comment: Also, what is your definition of "maximum sum" ? The whole tree would have a sum of 31, not 21.

Comment: @MSalters: the whole tree is a binary tree but not a binary search tree. The OP asks for the maximum sum of a binary search tree subtree.

Answer (score 0):

> Any node in a tree T, together with all the nodes below it, comprise a subtree of T.
> (http://subtree.askdefine.com/)

So if you include the root node then you need to include its descendants to the left as well as the right. As @user2357112 pointed out, this would mean that the subtree wouldn't be a BST.

Answer (score -2):

A possibility is that the definition of "subtree" requires that when you include a node in the subtree, you must include all of its descendants with it. This would mean that a subtree is entirely characterized by its subroot.

Comment: Yes, the misunderstanding seems to be what constitutes a "sub-tree". I was of the opinion that in a binary tree ANY parent-with-child was a subtree but I guess I was wrong(at least when it comes to this problem statement).

Comment: That's not how the usual definition works at all. The usual definition of a binary search tree allows nodes with 1 child. Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to add elements one at a time.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I agree with your definition of a binary search tree. But the question here is about the definition of a *subtree* of a given binary search tree.